# How do I maximize the function $W=\min(u_1,u_2)$ subject to the constraint $u_1^2+u_2^2=100$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

How do I maximize the function $W=\min(u_1,u_2)$ subject to the constraint $u_1^2+u_2^2=100$?

Usually I would do a Langrangian on the function to be maximized, but here it is difficult to do so.

The diagram I believe looks somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: If they are different, WLOG assume $u_1<u_2$, then $W=u_1<\sqrt{50}$. But if they are equal...

Comment: If you want to use calculus it might be helpful to know that $$\min(u_1, u_2) = \frac{u_1 + u_2 - |u_1 - u_2|}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove first that one of the variables must be $\le \sqrt{50}$. Assume the contrary. Let $u_1, u_2 > \sqrt{50}$, then we have:

$$u_1^2 + u_2^2 > 50 + 50 > 100$$

A contradiction.

From this we conclude that maximum of W is $\le \sqrt{50}$. Now to find when the maximum of $W = \sqrt{50}$ occurs. Assume $u_1 \ge u_2 = \sqrt{50}$. Then we have:

$$100 = u_1^2 + u_2^2 \ge 50 + 50 = 100$$

From this we conclude that $u_1 = \sqrt{50}$. So the maximum of $W$ occurs when $u_1 = u_2 = \sqrt{50}$

Comment: Suppose we are maximizing the same function but the constraint is different now: it's an ellipse, say $u_1^2+2u_2^2=100$. Then this kind of an argument would be complicated from my understanding of your answer.

Comment: @user36829 It would require little bit more calculation because the constrain isn't symetric, but it isn't that much more complicated. Here's some help: Prove that $W \le \sqrt{\frac{100}{3}}$ pushing the same argument (contradiction). 

Then just check the cases $u_1 \ge u_2 = \sqrt{\frac{100}{3}}$ and $u_2 \ge u_1 = \sqrt{\frac{100}{3}}$

Comment: I have followed your argument and found out that the maximum of $W$ in this case occurs when $u_1=u_2=\frac{\sqrt{100}}{\sqrt{3}}$. Thanks for your help.